# For distinct primes p and q that are $3$ mod $4$, $(−1, p)_\mathbb{Q}$ is not isomorphic to $(−1, q)_\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: quaternions, noncommutative-algebra, division-ring

For distinct primes p and q that are $3$ mod $4$, the quaternion algebras over the rationals, $(−1, p)_\mathbb{Q}$ is not isomorphic
to $(−1, q)_\mathbb{Q}$.

---

Any help prove it? I'm able to show that $(−1, q)_\mathbb{Q}$ is a division ring, for a prime $q =$ 3 mod 4

Answer (score 0):

There is an important norm criterion for the isomorphism of quaternion algebras with a common slot (outside characteristic $2$): for a field $F$ not of characteristic $2$, and nonzero $a, b, b'$ in $F$, we have $(a,b)_F \cong (a,b')_F$ if and only if $b/b' = x^2 - ay^2$ for some $x$ and $y$ in $F$.  (This is roughly analogous to $F(\sqrt{d}) \cong F(\sqrt{d'})$ if and only if $d/d' = x^2$ for some $x \in F$, where $d$ and $d'$ are nonsquares in $F$.)

If you don't know this criterion, read up on it.  If you know it, then apply it.

Comment: i know this criterion, but we didn't see it in class. any way there is an easier solution in this specific case?

Comment: Try to think of a structural property that $(-1,p)_\mathbf Q$ has that $(-1,q)_\mathbf Q$ doesn't (a norm value?).  Anyway, since you want your answer to depend on what has been taught in class, and we don't know what your class has covered, ask the instructor for advice.